# Redefining image height in PHP

Tags: php, image

I have dynamic loaded images wich cannot be larger than 115px. I get them from an external source so I have no control over it.

I could get the image sizes with:

```
$list = getimagesize($imagePath);
$width = $list[0];
$height = $list[1];
```

But now I need to resize if they are larger than 115px. Tried this but it didn't keep the proportion:

```
$height = round(($height * $width) / $width);
```

Can someone help me with this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need to actually resize the image and save it or are you showing it in html using an <img>?

Comment: `(height * width) / width == height`  That's probably why the math didn't work out for ya.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using [imagecopyresampled](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php) or [imagecopyresized](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php).

If you're looking to keep the image scaled properly, you'll have to throw in a bit more arithmetic, but it shouldn't be too bad.

Here's a bit of pseudocode for scaling the image:

```
$max_height = 115;
if ($height > $max_height)
{
    $scale = $max_height / $height;
    $height = intval($height * $scale);
    $width  = intval($width  * $scale);
}
```

Here's a more generic form for if height *and* width must be less than 115:

```
$max_size = 115;
if (max($height, $width) > $max_size)
{
    $scale = $max_size / max($height, $width);
    $height = intval($height * $scale);
    $width  = intval($width  * $scale);
}
```

This guarantees that the largest dimension of the image (be it height or width) will be no greater than 115.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean they can't be larger than 115x115. The process you'd have to go by is something like:

If wider than 115, set width to be 115px and height = height/original_width * 115;

I have some code from an image uploader script which does this

```
    list($Width, $Height) = getimagesize($row["img_file"]);

    if(($Width > $Height) && ($Width > 115))
    {
        $Height = ceil(($Height / $Width) * 115) ;
        $Width = 115;
    }
    elseif(($Height > $Width) && ($Height > 115))
    {
        $Width = ceil(($Width / $Height)* 115);
        $Height = 115;
    }
    elseif(($Height > 115) && ($Height == $Width))
    {
        $Height = 115;
        $Width = 115;
    }
```

After you have the correct dimensions you can resize the image using imagecreatefromjpeg/png/gif and then imagecopyresampled.

Another section of code from the image upload script which resized images from URLs using the calculated dimensions

```
        if ($extension == "png")
        {
            $image = imagecreatefrompng($URLofImage)or die("Width Of Image: ".$widthofImage." Height Of Image: ".$heightofImage." Height: ".$height." Width: ".$width);
            $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($widthofImage, $heightofImage)or die("Width Of Image: ".$widthofImage." Height Of Image: ".$heightofImage." Height: ".$height." Width: ".$width);
            imagealphablending($image_p, false);
            $color = imagecolorallocatealpha($image_p, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            imagesavealpha($image_p, true);
            list($width, $height) = getimagesize($URLofImage);

            imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $widthofImage, $heightofImage, $width, $height);
            imagepng($image_p, "./images/thumbs/".$name, 9);

            return ("./images/thumbs/".$name);
        }
```

Comment: You can simplify that a good bit: `if (max($height, $width) > $max_size) { $scale = $max_size / max($height, $width); $height *= $scale; $width *= $scale; }`

Answer (score 0):

You should just look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php#97564 it very direct

```
$max_width = 115; 
$max_height = 115;

list($width, $height) = getimagesize($imagePath);
$ratioh = $max_height/$height;
$ratiow = $max_width/$width;
$ratio = min($ratioh, $ratiow);

// New dimensions
$width = intval($ratio * $width);
$height = intval($ratio * $height);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your proportion is lets say height/width ratio, so put it to a variable:

> $ratio = $width/$height;

If you have a image like this: 100x200 px, your ratio is **1/2**. If you would like to have an image that has 20px height, the width sould be 10 px.

> $newHeight = 20;
>
> $newWidth = round( $newHeight * $ratio ); //gives you 10

Also lets say you would like to make the width 10px, just use this for to find new width:

> $newWidth = 10;
>
> $newHeight = round( $newWidth / $ratio );

So you should specify at least one edge length, then ratio will help you to find other edge.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your minimum browser requirement, and that this is indeed intended for HTML output you could handle this in html, and save yourself some processing.

```
<img alt='image alt' src='imagesrc' style='max-width:115px; max-height:115px; height:auto; width:auto;' />
```